# After saving the custom form it should direct to custom admin grid but directing to dashboard with the invalid key message and saving the data too

Tags: database, custom-admin-grid, insertlisting

How to solve invalid security and form key issue?[image: after insertion of the data it is reflecting the admin grid with this message]

Comment: Can you please add code to the question.

Comment: I want to add the action column with the edit and delete option  and followed this but only edit option is coming not the delete one could you please help me after clicking the edit button how it will work for the edit operation?

Comment: could you plwase tell me how to delete the row in the admin grid